# jQuery is not defined and jquery conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I purchased today the plugin called slider revolution from envato and use it on my website. I followed their step by step installation guides but when i open the console of my browser it gives me 2 errors "jQuery is not defined​" and "jQuery(...).revolution is not a function​".

I am also using other jquery plugins inside the site and i think there must be a conflict.

Below are all the calls for the jquery files and the javascript code from the slider plugin

```
    <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/creative.js"></script>

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {      
       $("#slider1").revolution({
          sliderType:"standard",
          sliderLayout:"auto",
          delay:7000,
          navigation: {
              arrows:{enable:true}              
          },            
          gridwidth:1230,
          gridheight:720        
        });     
    }); 
</script>
```

Related URL: http://webcy.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: The "revolution..." scripts that give you "jQuery is not defined" are loaded in your document's `<head>`. jQuery itself is loaded much later, at the end of the body. jQuery needs to be loaded before scripts that call it.

Answer (score 0):

From the source it looks like the revolution scripts are added at top (i.e in header). But jquery plugin is included at bottom. Please move the jQuery script to top. It should fix the issue

Comment: now it gives errors "TypeError: t is undefined" "TypeError: e is undefined" and "TypeError: $(...).revolution is not a function"

Comment: sorry mate didn't fixed the problem